# Is there a SQL Statement that allows me to copy and insert existing rows but with one column change?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

You might not understood what I want to ask from the title but ,here is the explanation.

I have a data in Oracle database table. What I wanted to do is insert a new data to the table. This new data is based on the existing data but I have to change the value of one columns. So if I have 10 rows in the database after the insertion i will have 20 rows but the new 10 rows contain the same data except on of the columns is changed.

E.g  table before insertion a new data

```
 Col1   Col2    Col3

  a       b       AA

  1       2       33
```

table after insertion a new data

```
 Col1   Col2    Col3

  a       b       **BB**

  1       2       **44**
```

Comment: But how do you supply the values for this new column? Where they come from?

Comment: This depends on the specific way that you want your data to change. If the new data can be *calculated* from the old data using standard Oracle SQL functions, then there is a simple solution; if the change is custom, then there is a considerably more complex solution.

Comment: Oh, its going to be hard coded on the query. Lets say, I want to change Col3 from AA too BB. So on the query I would say ... Col3=BB....

Comment: @MatX - And what about the other records? Or will ***all*** the records being inserted have a value of `'BB'` for Col3?

Comment: @Dems Exactly ... for one of the columns .. all the data is going to be the same (its just changing a year from 2010 to 2011). However, I found that I should do calculation (adding 6) for one of the columns. How do I do that?

Comment: @MatX - In my answer below, you just put your calculation what I have written `<Some SQL>`. For example, `Col3 + 6`. To test if it works, skip the whole `INSERT` section, and just write a `SELECT` - Once you have the `SELECT` giving you the results you want to insert, put the `INSERT` before it, and it will push the results of the `SELECT` into your table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that you can encode what the new value should be; yes.

```
INSERT INTO
  myTable (
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3
  )
SELECT
  Col1,
  Col2,               -- This is a specific example based on your comment.
  Col3 + 6            -- This just adds 6 to the existing value, but any SQL
FROM                  -- could actually go here, such as a CASE statement...
  myTable
```

So, the question becomes; Do you have rules that you can implement in SQL for calculating the new value for `Col3`?

The rules could be something basic like...

```
CASE WHEN Col3 = 'AA' THEN '**BB**'
     WHEN Col3 = '33' THEN '**44**'
                      ELSE 'Unknown'
END,
```

Or you could have all the new values in another table and look them up using a join...

```
INSERT INTO
  myTable (
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3
  )
SELECT
  OldTable.Col1,
  OldTable.Col2,
  COALESCE(NewTable.Col3, 'Unknown')
FROM
  myTable     AS OldTable
LEFT JOIN
  lookup      AS NewTable
    ON  OldTable.Col1 = NewTable.Col1
    AND OldTable.Col2 = NewTable.Col2
```

Or a whole bunch of other options.

Comment: I only need to do one more thing. Adding a value 6 (which is a number field) to one of the columns. How should I do that?

Comment: Do I have to mention all the columns? Like the id of that table (it is generated by the oracle db). The syntax seems to work but it is not affecting any rows.

Comment: INSERT INTO Ma.Table1( col1, col2, col3, col4 , col5)
SELECT 3, 
         col2 + 10,
         col3,
         col4,
         col5
         
    FROM Ma.Table1;

Comment: @MaxX - You need to mention all the fields you would normally mention when inserting data.  Even though you are copying from the original table, it behaves as if it's completely new data.  It's just a coincidence that your SELECT statement uses data from the same table that you are inserting into.

Answer (score 4):

It will depend on how you determine how to change the data.  How do you know, for example, that `AA` should become `BB` or that `33` should become `44`?

Something like this will work for the two cases you posted.  You can adapt it to whatever rule you want by changing the `CASE` statement to compute the new value differently.

```
INSERT INTO table_name( col1, col2, col3 )
  SELECT col1,
         col2,
         (CASE WHEN col3 = 'AA' 
                 THEN 'BB'
               WHEN col3 = '33'
                 THEN '44'
               ELSE null
            END)
    FROM table_name;
```